# cdh3 client interoperable with apache hadoop server 0.20.xx?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

we have a `hadoop-core-0.20.2-cdh3u1.jar` based java client. 
Would it be safe to work against a server (cluster) running apache distributed 0.20.xx? 
Or did cloudera break some apache APIs?

Thanks

Comment: i don't have an authoritative answer, but i certainly wouldn't advise it!

Answer (score 2):

probably a bad idea. Tried working with a client using hadoop-core version `0.20.203.0` against a server with cdh3u1 and got:

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$VersionMismatch: 
Protocol org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol version mismatch. (client = 61, server = 63)
```

Didn't try the other way around...