# Interoperability of pig 0.9.0 with cdh3u1?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

Softer version of [cdh3 client interoperable with apache hadoop server 0.20.xx?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10871442/574187)

We have a java app that runs a series of pig scripts (it injects some variables in them, but generally it's just a driver/client for running them). 
We need the macro features of pig 0.9.0 but cdh comes with pig 0.8.1. 
Is the following a good idea?

We try working with:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.2-cdh3u1</version>
    </dependency>
```

with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
        <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

instead of

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
        <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1-cdh3u1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: in which maven pom file are you trying to replace the pig dependency version?, or is this in your own UDF code project?

Comment: improved phrasing to explain - the java project the pom is a part of isn't a udf code project, its the client running the pig scripts (using PigServer.registerScript)